DynamoDB Export to S3 proper order of files / timestamps
I want to use DynamoDB’s Export-to-S3 feature for incremental load - just wondering how are each json.gz files’ timestamps would work? I’m not sure if I could safely use the S3 file timestamp for the respective order of changes as it's not stated in the documentation. There is the metadata for the export but not sure about how each items have changed can be tracked properly.
For context, I will be using this to perform CDC as this will be ingested in our Snowflake data warehouse.

Each item provides the timestamp (in microseconds) of when the item was last changed during the incremental export window. If your application can support microsecond precision then you can use that value without issue.
Moreover, incremental export only stores the final image of an item, so for a given export, the item will only appear once.

Hi Leeroy, thanks for this. My goal is to capture all changes in an item, does that mean I need to access the smallest possible export window as much as possible? I know this can be handled with Kinesis streams but I’m trying to minimize cost..

15 mins is the minimum window, so unlikely suitable. Kinesis and Firehose are most likely your best option, if you need to see all changes.

I thought it was 5 minutes based on PITR, I missed the bit how export window difference should be >= 15 mins. I'll check in first to see how frequent updates would look like, if looking at 15mins window each is enough, then decide if I really need to look into Kinesis approach.
I have last 2 questions - how can I probably estimate maximum time of how long export would run? What are the factors that affect this? I have tested exporting and can't determine its factors. Using incremental export for 20 times - it ran from 5-17 mins.
Really appreciate your inputs, thanks so much.

It depends on how much data has changed, so the amount of data that you export. The skewness of the data also plays a factor. And finally, it runs as a task, so there can be a couple of mins for the task to be acknowledged and run.
